# python: regex to match pattern on multiple lines (apply to start of string)

Tags: python, string-matching

I'm trying to create a pattern to match two lines in the following multi-line text:

```
Text of no interest.
TextOfInterest1, foobar of no interest
another foobar of no interest
AnotherText-of_Interest2 some foobar don't care
```

I need to match exactly `TextOfInterest1` and `AnotherText-of_Interest2`, note that there might be multiple lines between `TextOfInterest1` and `AnotherText-of_Interest2`. I don't know how I can apply `^` symbol more than once in a single pattern string?

Comment: @ChrisCharley, what does `r'` mean? (pardon my ignorance, I don't use python on a regular basis, so don't know all :) )

Comment: @Mark The `r` before the string marks it as a raw string. This means that the backslash `\ ` character is treated normally and not as an escape character. This is typically used for regex and Windows filepaths.  Without it, you would have to use `\\d` to represent digits instead of just `\d`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pat = r"^.*\n([-_\w]+).*\n.*\n([-_\w]+).*$"
string="""Text of no interest.
TextOfInterest1, foobar of no interest
another foobar of no interest
AnotherText-of_Interest2 some foobar don't care"""

re.search(pat,string).groups()
```

```
('TextOfInterest1', 'AnotherText-of_Interest2')
```

Check pattern at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oxF8bm/1).

Comment: thanks for comment. Actually, I was not clear in my question (I updated it).

Comment: updated the pattern. Inside the character class `[]` you can define which characters are aloud to be in the text.